# infinite while loop gives java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java

if i want to run a while loop up to infinity and i am getting Java heap space but i am using "system garbage cleaner  " to clean up memory. so how can i solve this problem.

```
try{
    while(true){
        try{
            attach=sample.readMails();         
            System.gc();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error In  readMails-->downloads");
        }
    }
}catch (Exception e){
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Error In  Infinite While");
}
```

Comment: why would you need to run infinite loops without a condition to break the loop?

Comment: What does `readMails()` do?

Comment: You're invoking `System.gc()` but this doesn't mean that the GC will be invoked immediately.

Comment: Please post an minimal, complete, and verifiable example. (MCVE): http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `System.gc()` is just a hint to the runtime. If you have objects filling up memory that are not ready for collection, then they won't be collected.

Comment: An educated guess would suggest this guy: sample.readMails() is the problem - you won't get a decent answer unless we can see what is happening there.

Answer (score 0):

`System.gc` only works for unused objects.
According to docs of [System#gc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#gc--)

> Calling the gc method suggests that the Java Virtual Machine expend
>   effort toward recycling unused objects in order to make the memory
>   they currently occupy available for quick reuse.